# Mule ESB conditional Exchange pattern for UDP/TCP transport

Tags: tcp, request, mule, response

I need to send an acknowledge response for some messages went an acknowledge needed flag is set for that purpose.

Using a Java component I build a Payload string array with this structure:

```
Payload[0]=message entry.
Payload[1]="true"/"false" // This is the acknowledge needed flag. 
Payload[2]="OK"/"ON"/"OFF"// Response to the transport (went flag="true")
```

This is my XML code

```
<tcp:connector name="TCP" validateConnections="false" sendBufferSize="0" receiveBufferSize="0" receiveBacklog="0" keepAlive="true" clientSoTimeout="10000" serverSoTimeout="10000" socketSoLinger="0" doc:name="TCP">
    <tcp:direct-protocol rethrowExceptionOnRead="true" payloadOnly="true"/>
</tcp:connector>
    <flow name="verifyFlow">
    <tcp:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="9446" connector-ref="TCP" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="TCP" transformer-refs="Byte_Array_to_String"/>
    <component class="verify.as" doc:name="Java Component"/>
    <choice doc:name="Choice">
        <when expression="#[message.payload[1] == 'false']">
            <set-payload value="&quot;&quot;" doc:name="No response"/>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <expression-transformer mimeType="text/plain" expression="#[message.payload[2]]" doc:name="Expression"/>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
</flow>
```

The problem I'm facing is that went ever the flag is "false" there shouldn't be any response send to the transport (no 'null' value, no empty string, no "", Etc.) ¿Is there any way to change the exchange pattern of the TCP (or UDP) connector from request-response to one way inside the flow?

Comment: Hi, I don't think you can easily do it. Mule in any case will answer even in case of exception because this is how a request response pattern works.
If may try to raise an exception with a filter or in a groovy script to see if in case of exception mule is still answering on the TCP or just closing the socket.

Comment: Actually that what I did, I created a Exception with Groovy component
<code>
throw new IllegalArgumentException('Acknowledge false')

Comment: This stops the reply, but I was looking for a better way, if any.

Comment: This is the only fast way. Alternative is to extend and override methods on the transport.